# iPhone Dev = maps and deselecting annotations

Tags: iphone, mapkit, annotations

I am successfully drawing annotations on a map using an array of annotations. I can even click on the annotation and change it’s colour or image. My problem arises when the use selects the second annotation and I want to dynamically change the colour or image of the first one back to a non-selected colour/image. I can get the array of all the annotations and work through the array but once I try to set the colour or image ot the array I get a similar error.

```
for (MKAnnotationView *ann in map.selectedAnnotations){ 
  if ([ann isMemberOfClass:[Place class]]) { 
    place = (Place *)ann; 
      if (currentPlaceID != place.placeID) { 
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
        ann.image = i; 
      }
}
```

the above code works ok until I get to ann.image = i; then it errors. The errors I get are:-

> - -[Place setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4514370 Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[Place setImage:]:
>     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4514370'

Please advise as I have been going around in circles on this one for 2 days now!!!!

Any ideas on how best to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a property on the class Place called image?

Something like... `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* image;` and is it properly synthesized? `@synthesize image;`?

The error is pretty straight forward, some object is receiving a message that it doesn't respond to, namely 'setImage' which is invoked by the .image.

**Here is your code:**

```
1. for (MKAnnotationView *ann in map.selectedAnnotations) {
2.    if ([ann isMemberOfClass:[Place class]]) {
3.        place = (Place *)ann;
4.        if (currentPlaceID != place.placeID) {
5.           UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
6.           ann.image = i;
7.        }
8.    }
9. }
```

What I can see:

- ann is an MKAnnotationView (from map.selectedAnnotations)
- you are typecasting your annotation to a place on line 3 (is this right?  Does Place subclass MKAnnotationView?)
- you are properly setting the image to the annotation

What this means:

- If Place is indeed a subclass of MKAnnotationView, you hid the setImage (somehow) method
- If Place is NOT a subclass of MKAnnotationView, you've added an invalid annotation to the annotations (sure) that you're trying to treat as an annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will definitely try this but I don't think it will help as the image is drawn by setting the annotation not by - (void)setAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation not in the class place.

Comment: I want to change the image of the annotation not the property on the place object.

Comment: Right, however you are 1) casting your annotation to a Place and 2) then sending it the message '.setImage'.  This is most likely NOT what you want to do.  (See the edit which is coming in a minute)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this.  As usual it's not that hard once you know how.  Just thought I would pass this on.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    NSLog(@"here I am in set selected");
    if (YES == selected)
    {
       NSLog(@"I am selected");
    }
    else 
   {
     self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      NSLog(@"not selected");
    }
  }
```